# Lauterbach hexdump address range into file

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

How do I hexdump by using range (e.g. 0xA0000000 - 0xA000FFFF) into a hex file using Trace32 scripting language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data.save.IntelHex output.hex 0xA0000000--0xA000FFFF
```

or equivalent

```
data.save.IntelHex output.hex 0xA0000000..0xA000FFFF
```